# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on my same domain but w/o 'www'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, dns

Not sure what i'm doing wrong in my htaccess or so, but when I access my website from `http://example.org` instead of `http://www.example.org` it throws this error:

```
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
 Origin 'http://example.org' is therefore not allowed access.
```

how do i setup my htaccess or my server apache to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`www.example.com` and `example.com` are different origins. To be the same origin, the *complete* hostname, the port and the scheme have to match.

You have three options:

- Set up CORS to grant access from one to the other.
- When doing Ajax, use relative URIs instead of absolute ones.
- Pick one to be canonical and stop hosting your website off the other.

The last approach is probably the best.

1. Change all your links to be relative or to point to example.com
2. Set up HTTP 301 Redirects for everything on www.example.com to example.com

Comment: thanks! i'm using absolute URls because I have product pages like example.org/sku/3847/some-name/ so if i coudl solve that i wont need absolute urls

Comment: Use absolute paths and leave the rest of the URL relative. `href="/sku/etc/etc"`

Comment: duh. i feel so dumb... I did setup absolute urls for some old reason that i forgot, now i changed in my config to "/" and everythin works perfectly!